# How to make a pattern to change x^(2/y) to (x^2)^(1/y) for any x and y?

Tags: programming, pattern-matching

This might have been asked before. Please let me know if it is.

I was looking at an interesting Mathematica question in students forum and trying to solve it, and a chance to learn more about patterns.

Having little hard time writing a general pattern to convert an expression `anything^(2/anything)` to `(anything^2)^(1/anything)`

For example, given `(-1/3)^(2/3)` , convert this to `((-1/3)^2)^(1/3)` and when given `(-1/3)^(2/z)` convert it to `((-1/3)^2)^(1/z)` which then simplifies to `(1/9)^(1/z)`

The problem is that the FullForm changes depending if it is a symbol or a number in the exponent:

```
FullForm[(-1/3)^(2/6)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullForm[(-1/3)^(2/z)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Will there be other general `FullForm(s)` to check for other than these two?

For `Rational` (numbers) this is how I do it now:

```
 (-1/3)^(2/3)/. 
 Power[Rational[-1,x_],Rational[2,y_]]:>Power[Power[Rational[-1,x],2],Rational[1,y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might have wondered why I did not write the more direct way:

```
(-3^(-1))^(2/3) /. (x_)^(2/y_) :> (x^2)^(1/y)
```

Well, because the above does not work. So, I cheated and looked at the `FullForm` and used that above in the pattern.

But the above fails when the denominator is a symbol, for example `2/z` instead of numbers `2/3`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I need little help figuring how how to check for each case. If I know it is a symbol, then `Times[2, Power[z_, -1]]` can be used. If it is not numeric, then `Rational[2, z_]` can be used.

**question is**: How to write a general pattern to convert `x^(2/y)` to `(x^2)^(1/y)` for any `x` and any `y` (excluding edge cases like Infinity, Indeterminate, {}, zero, and such. Just for numerics and symbols. This is practical problem.

**Update**

I was pointed out in the chat room to an old Mathematica package which was designed to handle such cases. But this package is no longer available.  On the right below, is a screen shot of that old package from WRI page, the left is current V9 result

[image]

Here is the old package  link http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/StandardPackages/Miscellaneous/RealOnly.html   (thanks for P.Fonseca for the link)

The original question from a student at the WRI forum as asking for the behavior given by this old package (i.e. not the complex root, but show the real root).

Comment: Perhaps `a_^((2/b_) | Rational[2, b_]) :> (a^2)^b`?. `:> (Defer[a]^2)^Defer[b]` to see the output

Comment: Do you just want an unevaluated expression?

Comment: Note also that your title and 3rd sentence asks for x^(2/y) to (x^2)^y whereas the 4th sentence and final paragraph asks for x^(2/y) to (x^2)^(1/y). etc. etc. Can you clean this up by removing these contradictions.

Comment: I mean unevaluated in the generic sense because you clearly want to halt a full evaluation and ensure that `_^_` is the output pattern. In other words you don't want (1/9)^(1/3) to be evaluated any further do you?  ... so some "holding" of the expression is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm probably missing something, but maybe if you show me where this fails I can improve it:

```
rule = x_^(2/y_ | Rational[2, y_]) :> HoldForm[(x^2)^(1/y)];

{(-1/3)^(2/3), (-1/3)^(2/z)} /. rule
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Nasser I'm glad if this answer helps, but I can't say I understand what you're trying to do.  This transformation is only valid if the base (x) is non-negative, right, so of course there is a difference?  Isn't your result the same as `Abs`?